# Strtotime field from another table in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have bunch of dates (DATE field type) stored in one table and I need to find entries from second table with date not older than 5 months than in the first table. It should look something like this:

```
SELECT first_table.id, second_table.value
FROM first_table
  LEFT JOIN second_table
    ON second_table.lastupdate >= '".date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-150 days', strtotime(first_table.lastupdate)))."'
```

Of course, it is not working, that's just example for you to explain what I am trying to do. Now I use two queries to achieve the result, but it is not efficient at all as I have more than 300 000 entries in each table.

/*EDIT */
Table structures are:

```
first_table
id - (AUTO_INCREMENT INT)
lastupdate (DATE)

second_table
id - (AUTO_INCREMENT INT)
value - (VARCHAR)
lastupdate - (DATE)
```

**I need to filter by date stored in second_table, not todays' date.**

Comment: can you provide the table structure ?

Comment: you can do something like this: `SELECT first_table.id, second_table.value
FROM first_table 
  LEFT JOIN second_table 
    ON first_table.id=second_table.id WHERE  second_table.lastupdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 150 DAY`

Comment: what about `DATE_SUB` .... `>= DATE_SUB(first_table.lastupdate, INTERVAL 5 MONTH)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use this:

```
SELECT first_table.id, second_table.value
FROM first_table
LEFT JOIN second_table
ON second_table.lastupdate <= convert(first_table.lastupdate, Date) + interval 5 month
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT first_table.id, second_table.value FROM first_table AS ft LEFT JOIN second_table as st ON ft.first_table.id=st.second_table.id WHERE st.second_table.lastupdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 150 DAY
```

Comment: it's useless, because I need to look for a date stored in second table, not today date